# Should I use "base." prefix when accessing inherited property

Tags: c#, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is using “base” bad practice even though it might be good for readability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049908/is-using-base-bad-practice-even-though-it-might-be-good-for-readability)

I have a base class somewhat like this:

```
internal abstract class ResultRow : IResultRow
{
    protected InspectionDto InspectionDto { get; private set; }

    public ResultRow(InspectionDto inspectionDto)
    {
        InspectionDto = inspectionDto;
    }
}
```

And a number of classes inheriting `ResultRow` that look somewhat like this:

```
internal class RadioRow : ResultRow
{
    public RadioRow(InspectionDto inspectionDto) :
                base(inspectionDto) {}
}
```

When referring to the `InspectionDto` property in the inheriting class, should it be prefixed with `base.`, i.e. `base.InspectionDto`? In this case I'm using constructor injection to capture a common property that is only used in subclasses of `ResultRow` and it isn't virtual so won't be overridden. Using the `base.` prefix makes it explicit where the property is defined but it's not something I would normally do. I've seen it used recently and wondered if it was considered a good or bad practice and why.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't really matter, but whatever you choose stick to it and be consistent. It's the pattern (not the convention) that will help you and others in the future.

Personally, I prefer using `base`. Also, StyleCop recommends it.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely your call. Do it if you think it makes the code more readable!